# Why can't Scala infer the type of _?

Tags: scala, type-inference

I heard in Scala I can use `_` as "anonymous parameter" in anonymous function:

```
List(1,2,3).foreach(print(_))
```

But this code can't be compiled:

```
scala> def a[T](s: Seq[T]): Seq[T] = s.map(_)
<console>:7: error: missing parameter type for expanded function ((x$1) => s.map(x$1))
```

And this can:

```
scala> def a[T](s: Seq[T]): Seq[T] = s.map(x => x)
a: [T](s: Seq[T])Seq[T]
```

It seems about type inference. But how could `x => x` provide more information than `_`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The problem here is not a type inference.

As you can see from error message equivalent code for `s.map(_)` is not `s.map(x => x)`, but this:

```
i => s.map(i)
```

Just like `print(_)` (actually `Predef.print(_)`) means `i => Predef.print(i)`.

Or like `"a" + _` means `"a".+(_)` means `s => "a".+(s)`.

This just doesn't make sense in current context.

Let's suppose you have a list of functions `String => String` (`fs`) and you want to apply all these functions to list of `String`. You'll use this code:

```
fs.map{f => s.map(f)}
```

or just this:

```
fs.map{s.map(_)}
```

Addition: you could use `identity` method instead if `x => x`. It's imported by default, but you could make it even shorter using addition import:

```
import Predef.{identity => id}
List(1, 2, 3) map id
// List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)
```

Note that `identity` is a well known name, so in team you should use it instead of your aliases.

Comment: +1 Very intuitive explanation of the placeholder syntax.

Answer (score 0):

> It seems about type inference. But how could x => x provide more information than _?

x => x is a type of Function1, which is what the map function expects as parameter.  The compiler can't infer that the anonymous variable _ of type T is really a Function1.